# How to record a pcap file in FLoRa for OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++, flora

I used the following code in the preexisting flora simulation omnetpp.ini file to record a pcap of the generated network traffic. the code is derived from the INET package, where it works flawless.

I tried:

```
# pcap recorder settings
**.pcapRecorder[*].alwaysFlush = true
**.crcMode = "computed"         
**.fcsMode = "computed"

# network server pcap
*.networkServer.numPcapRecorders = 1
*.networkServer.pcapRecorder[*].pcapLinkType = 1    # ethernet: 1
*.networkServer.pcapRecorder[*].pcapFile = "results/networkServer_eth.pcap"
*.networkServer.pcapRecorder[*].moduleNamePatterns = "eth[*]"
```

After a short while running the simulation outputs the following error:

> Cannot find serializer for flora::LoRaMacFrame -- in module (inet::UdpCrcInsertionHook) LoRaNetworkTest.loRaGW[0].udp.crcInsertion

Does anybody have an idea how to easily fix this? Unfortunately I am not good with C++.

Comment: I think I had a similar issue in other OMNeT++ modules and setting `**.pcapRecorder[*].packetFilter = "*"` helped. Could you try and report?

Comment: unfortunately didn't change anything. thanks anyways!